Thunderbird layout configuration trouble
I've recently been given my 7th email address from a new company. I'm tired of keeping all tabs open on my browser. I decided to look into thunderbird. I'm exceptionally confused and frustrated at what appears to be a glaring lack of a basic feature but I seriously doubt it's thunderbird's fault so I'm reaching out here for help and education. I cannot figure out how to view a conversation chronologically. My inbox contains ONLY received messages. If I replied to those messages, those replies are not in the inbox. I have to go to "sent" to see what I wrote and try to mentally lace the conversation together. I was recommended to use Thunderbird Conversations add on....however, after installing that add on, while it does accomplish the goal of keeping my thread in order, if I receive a new message in a thread, the top level message doesn't indicate that THAT specific thread is the one with the new reply. So if I have 10 threads in my inbox, my "unread messages" counter will show that I've received a new message but the top level message of every thread doesn't indicate that it's the thread with a new message. I end up having to go through and expand every thread to see which one has a highlighted, unread message.
Is there some setting I'm missing because I feel this should be the configuration out of the box. I can't imagine a single scenario in all of earth where a person genuinely does not want to see their own replies in a thread and specifically wants to go view their responses in a separate folder without context of what exact message they were replying to.
